# Apache Guacamole on Docker does not respond

Tags: docker, docker-compose, guacamole

I followed Linode's guide [1] to the letter and I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` from `<server-address>:8080/guacamole`

The machine where Docker is running is Almalinux 8.5 minimal therefore I cannot open a browser to localhost on the machine itself, I have to connect from another machine.

There are no firewall issues as through tcpdump I see the TCP handshake [2]

I also ran another docker example with a simple http server and it worked.

This is the output of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS                       NAMES
62eb7fe99f15   guacamole/guacamole   "/opt/guacamole/bin/…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes                 127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp    example-guacamole
e67dbb2b3273   guacamole/guacd       "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes (healthy)       4822/tcp                    example-guacd
cb03bd35d482   mysql/mysql-server    "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes (healthy)       3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp   example-mysql
```

SELinux has been disabled with `setenforce 0` [3] and the firewall has been stopped with `systemctl stop firewalld` [4]

I suspect that this has something to do with the network, it's as if the host machine does not forward the incoming connection to the docker container. I should probably run this environment through docker-compose. I ran a similar setup (chirpstack) a couple of years ago and I remember fiddling with the "network" properties of docker-compose.yml but I don't have any backup and I don't remember how I did it.

How should I debug this? What am I missing?

[1] https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/installing-apache-guacamole-through-docker/

[2]

```
[root@localhost guacamole]# tcpdump -nni ens192 port 8080
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:53:57.059020 IP 172.30.254.254.53121 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [SEW], seq 4213614549, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.059163 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53121: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 4213614550, win 0, length 0
10:53:57.059411 IP 172.30.254.254.53122 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [SEW], seq 1710300584, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.059471 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53122: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1710300585, win 0, length 0
10:53:57.309756 IP 172.30.254.254.53124 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [SEW], seq 103230931, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.309823 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53124: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 103230932, win 0, length 0
10:53:57.559317 IP 172.30.254.254.53121 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 4213614549, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.559410 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53121: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
10:53:57.560156 IP 172.30.254.254.53122 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 1710300584, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.560236 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53122: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
10:53:57.810286 IP 172.30.254.254.53124 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 103230931, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:57.810355 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53124: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
10:53:58.060306 IP 172.30.254.254.53122 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 1710300584, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:58.060377 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53122: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
10:53:58.060434 IP 172.30.254.254.53121 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 4213614549, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:58.060475 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53121: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
10:53:58.310360 IP 172.30.254.254.53124 > 172.30.5.50.8080: Flags [S], seq 103230931, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:53:58.310458 IP 172.30.5.50.8080 > 172.30.254.254.53124: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
```

[3]

```
[root@localhost guacamole]# getenforce
Permissive
[root@localhost guacamole]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33
```

[4]

```
[root@localhost guacamole]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-07-21 16:56:20 CEST; 18h ago
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
PORTS
127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp
```

If I'm connecting from another machine it should be

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

So with respect to the Linode guide I changed from this

```
docker run --name example-guacamole --link example-guacd:guacd --link example-mysql:mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=guacamole_user_password -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole
```

to this

```
docker run --name example-guacamole --link example-guacd:guacd --link example-mysql:mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=guacamole_user_password -d -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole
```

and I can now connect to the Apache Guacamole homepage